# Corrupted look and feel in java windowing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

everyone
I got corrupted components in Java swing applicatoin, once started to use Look and Feel class.

In my java swing app, before use of any look and feel, and the gui looked boring and flat.  However, look at this screenshot

[image]

I started using Nimbus Look and feel by adding this to the code

```
UIManager.put("control", new Color(210, 210, 210)) ; 
    UIManager.put("TextField.background", new Color(250, 250, 210)) ;
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", new Color(250, 250, 210))      
      ;


    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {         
    }
```

and now, that same window on the screenshot is corrupted

[image]

What's going on?  How to fix it ??  Does anyone know?

Editing after some replies in comments.  Than you people for bringing up the matter of re sizing the window.

========================================================================
Here is how it is the example of how it is done: (The code is not completely mine, and many of the windows were not made by me, so I have to dive there and analyze it all)

```
    pack();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setSize(new Dimension(570, 700));   
    setLocation((screenSize.width-450)/2,(screenSize.height-550)/2);
```

Once, I remove the code below pack(), I don't have the corrupted GUI problem.
I did notice, however that the whole window became taller and thinner than it was.

Also, while on the subject.
I am giving the new LookAndFeel to my application by using the code spinet above (in a try-catch)
I can also do it via -D JVM Options.  What is generally a better or a more acceptable way? 
From my understanding I think it is better done in the code, since there I can use UIManager.put(key, value) to narrow down particular colors or properties of the new look and feel.  I tried doing that when using -D JVM Options, but It doesn't pick it up.  The window still looks the same way, no matter if I change colors in the code or not.

Comment: You are probably hardcoding sizes somewhere in your code. Don't use `setPreferredSize(...)` or `setBounds(,,)` or `setLayout(null)`. Use layout managers and let the layout manager do its job.

Comment: Can you post examples of how your code is sizing elements, or using the layout manager?  Doing so will allow @camickr to turn their comment into an answer so they can get rep.

Comment: Another thing that would cause this is hard-coding the size of the window instead of relying on `pack()`.  If a GridBagLayout doesn’t have enough room to give each component its preferred size, it reverts to using the *minimum* size of each component.

Comment: Provide a suggest  `column` count to the textfields, so they generate a preferred size based on the font been used

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the matter of size.  Yes, I did have a setSize() every there and here around the code after pack().
I edited original post to put the code spinet.

Comment: Well, removing setSize doesn't fix it everywhere.
It is a large swing based system with many windows, when I started to use 
nimbus look and feel, it crooked some of the windows.
I removed setSize, and it got crooked some other way.
I start to increase the size and it seem to fix it.  However, when other people use laptops with smaller screens, they loose part of a screen.  
Anything to suggest ?